# How to see reports in web application using .jrxml or .jasper file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have designed .jrxml jasper report or after compilation got .jasper file using ireport 5.1 tool. I am using tomacat server 7 & i don't want to write code in .jsp page .

Now, i want when i click button on jsp page, the report in pdf should be able to see. For that which jars should i use in pom.xml(Maven) or what java code should i write ? What should be the proper approach to do this task ?

I am not getting even the starting point to perform this task.

Please Help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [this dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.0)  :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find some documentation about how to use it in [the Ultimate guide available (free)](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation).

But If you simply want to upload your jrxml files and see the result why not use [jasperreports-server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server) ?

It is a full web application that can be deployed directly on the application server of your choice.